# Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests)

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.NET website that sometimes gets high traffic, the below error message recently appears to me:

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests)
```

I asked the support to solve it but they find a solution, they moved the website to another server then it works fine for a couple of days then the error appears again.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is there a setting in IIS to avoid such error and to reset the limit if it reaches the peak?
BTW: The support claims that they are not putting limits on the number of connections and they said that they have increased the application pool's memory which I think will do nothing with this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks doesn't like a status code that should be returned from IIS but CLR. Have you monitored how many request are being processed when your application return 429 error？ It looks just like too many concurrent requests are being processed in the same worker process.  I think you could try to reproduce and capture dump file. By analyzing the dump file, we would know how to fix this

Comment: @JokiesDing thanks for your response, I'll contact the support to get the dump file and will back to you shortly, the concurrent requests are not more than 1500-2000 per second.

Comment: The support team refused to give me the dump file!

Comment: It is really tough to find the root cause if support team refuse to send you dump file. Have you tried to expand the number of max worker processes?